# Research Director not responding to email - should I call him?

Tags: email

I'm posting this question because normally he is a very punctual person, often responding within a matter of hours if our time zones match up. However, I sent an email last week and a follow-up one on Sunday, and he has yet to read it (according to my email-tracking software).

I don't think his university has started break yet, so should I wait a little bit and leave a message?

Edit: Question should not be considered a duplicate because I am inquiring as to whether I should call him now that email seems to be "exhausted" so to speak, but I'm not sure if calling is appropriate.

Comment: Assume that the prof is busy.

Comment: Your email tracking software doesn't work. Like many others, I have disabled the sending of acknowledgements of receipt, because I find those requests highly intrusive.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101950/professors-teachers-only-replying-to-part-of-my-email

Answer (score 3):

Before you call him, email the department receptionists and ask if the Research Director is around. It's possible he's on holiday, he's on bereavement leave or paternity leave, he's attending a conference, and so on. The department receptionists are likely to be more familiar with his schedule than most. If they say he's around, you can also ask them to pass a message to the Research Director.