# Professor not replying to my email. Why?

Tags: professorship, email, exams

I wrote an email to my professor yesterday to ask makeup exam. But he doesn't reply until now.

Test was taken a week ago. But, I can't take it because of family emergency(my grandfather passed away) and sudden move into new room (my hostfamily kicked me out without prior notice.I think the reason is outbreak of covid-19, and I'm Asian). Those are my nightmare!

In your opinion, can he admit my makeup test? and why doesn't he reply my email...?

Comment: I do not have Internet access at home.  I only come into the office on days I have (now by Internet) classes, for the obvious reason.  This is 3 days a week.  For situations like this, I probably wait two days to respond, because I want to make sure to think through all the angles before a decision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ignoring emails acceptable in academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/is-ignoring-emails-acceptable-in-academia) See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101950/professors-teachers-only-replying-to-part-of-my-email?r=SearchResults

Comment: How should be possibly know the prof and the answer?!

Comment: Makeup exams procedures depend on institution. Sometimes it's the professor who decides the process, sometimes the institution. Are you sure this is the decision of the professor and not the institution? Please note that you will most likely have to provide evidence for your emergency situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expecting an overnight reply to any email is unrealistic. He may have some issues of his own to deal with, given the worldwide pandemic. He will probably reply "in good time", but by his standards.

Whether you are allowed to take a make up or not we can't say here. It is up to him and to the institution. I hope it is allowed and expect it would be given the family emergency. But the other things you mention have little bearing on the issue.

But waiting a week after the missed exam wasn't wise, and expecting an instant reply after you didn't offer an explanation for a week is a bit "over the top".

I suggest that you wait to see what the reply is. There probably isn't really a *need* for instant action at this point.